# How to Wakeup from Sleep during CAN network state transition?

Tags: embedded, can-bus, autosar, pdu, automotive

I am trying to understand the CAN network management of AUTOSAR. I am trying to sleep the ECU if there are no CAN message received during IGN cycle. I am blocking the CAN transmission and reception during this stage. Now suppose AUTOSAR NM message is received, i want to make the ECU to wakeup and need to make CAN to be full active. I have gone through the basic Autosar Network management understanding.

As per my understanding

`If communication on the bus is needed i.e. requested, NM messages are sent out. If no communication is needed i.e. released, sending of NM messages is stopped.`

When the Autosar NM state is "Ready Sleep state" or "Repeat Message State", I am waking up the CAN. I would like to know, this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: AUTOSAR_SWS_CANNetworkManagement.pdf

You need to read detail the state diagram in section 7.20 for the state and possible transition.

The wake-up and sleep in network management means the communication state. And the specification defines the state to synchronize between ECUs in vehicle. For examples:

- During bus-sleep state is state that you disable the CAN controller and CAN transceiver.
- During wake-up, you will initiate the communication state again for full communication.

### Note: Beware about the state of sending/receiving the NM message because it is sync signal for all ECUs.

Comment: What is bus-sleep state here ? Is it "Ready Sleep state" ? Also why we required Repeat Message State? Anyway I will go through this document.

Comment: Bus-sleep when transceiver is in standby or sleep. "Ready Sleep state" is the period that no communication needed, just checking if some communication wake again.